# JSON to Pandas Dataframe types change

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have JSON output from m3inference package in python like this:

```
{'input': {'description': 'Bundeskanzlerin',
       'id': '2631881902',
       'img_path': '/root/m3/cache/angelamerkeicdu_224x224.jpg',
       'lang': 'de',
       'name': 'Angela Merkel',
       'screen_name': 'angelamerkeicdu'},
 'output': {'age': {'19-29': 0.0,
                '30-39': 0.0001,
                '<=18': 0.0001,
                '>=40': 0.9998},
        'gender': {'female': 0.9991, 'male': 0.0009},
        'org': {'is-org': 0.0032, 'non-org': 0.9968}}}
```

I store it in:

`org = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(org['output']), orient='columns')`

```
        gender.male  gender.female  age.<=18  ...  age.>=40  org.non-org  org.is-org
    0       0.0009         0.9991    0.0000  ...    0.9998       0.9968      0.0032
```

i dont know where is the `0` value in the first column coming from, I save `org.isorg` column to isorg

`isorg = org['org.is-org']`

but when i append it to panda data frame dtypes is object, the value is change to

`0 0.0032 Name: org.is-org, dtype: float64`

not `0.0032`

How to fix this?

Comment: To access the value the cell use `isorg[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i dont know where 0 value in first column coming from then i save org.isorg column to isorg"

That "0" is an index to your dataframe. Unless you specify your dataframe index, pandas will auto create the index. You can change you index instead.

code example:

```
org.set_index('gender.male', inplace=True)
```

Index is like an address to your data. It is how any data point across the dataframe or series can be accessed.